# Using "speaking" in the wrong context

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

While talking about how a movie hasn't created enough buzz, can one say "Why aren't people speaking about that movie?" and not use the verb 'talking' as is done usually?

Answer (score 4):

You absolutely can say that if you really, really want to, but as [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/speak-or-talk) points out, there is a subtle difference in meaning between **speak** and **talk**:

> Speak usually only focuses on the person who is producing the words:
>
> Talk focuses on a speaker and at least one listener, and can mean ‘have a conversation’:

since talking about a movie usually involves a discussion between multiple people, **talk** is the more appropriate verb to use.

Aside from that is the fact that **speak** is usually more formal than **talk** is, and a discussion about a movie is likely to be quite an informal chat between friends.

Comment: ...and it's more idiomatic to say "people are talking about". (At least it's more idiomatic here in the US to say "talk about" as opposed to "speak about").

Comment: Same here in the UK, but that again goes back to the fact that when people are "talking about" things it's a multi-way dialogue, rather than just one person producing words. Good comment, though.